# How do I make conditionals correct in firebase onAuthStateChanged()?

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, conditional-statements, react-navigation

I'm doing a `firebase` login in `react native`. When the user logs in I want the navigation to go to another view. And it does so with the code I'm using. Problem is, I don't get the conditionals right which makes the navigation statement trigger indefinitely. Here's the code:

```
  componentDidMount() {
fbAuth.onAuthStateChanged(user => this.myFunc(user));
}

myFunc(user) {
   if (user) {
     console.log("LOGGED IN");
     console.log(user);
     this.props.navigation.navigate("LoggedIn"); 
   } else {
     console.log("LOGGED OUT");
   }
}
```

Of course, it makes sense that the navigation statement is run indefinitely since `user` is passed as an argument. Honestly, I don't quite understand what `user` actually represent. Printed in console, it just writes lots of different info. What I want is something like this: `if(userHasSuccessfullyLoggedIn)` Any ideas?

***EDIT*** 
Problems:
* As soon as I enter the page, the navigation triggers for some reason.
* If I go back and enter correct mail and pass login works, but the navigation is triggered twice for some reason. 
* Registering a new account also triggers the navigation twice.

Comment: If successfully authenticated `onAuthStateChanged` returns an instance of [`firebase.User`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User) or `null` if unsuccessful.

Comment: The auth method takes care about if the response was successful or not as @svendjokumsen said it correctly

Comment: by `fbauth.onAuthStateChanged` do you mean this method: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#onAuthStateChanged? If yes then what is `fbAuth` object?